# How to free the memory used by a new class to avoid memory leak?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, memory-leaks, backgroundworker

I am using following code. As I saw this one in .Net memory profiler I found memory leaks are occurring .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace TestMemLeak
 {
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {

    public int count = 0;
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   public  class test 
    {
        public int sno{get; set;}
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
        public string col4 { get; set; }
        public string col5 { get; set; }
        public string col6 { get; set; }
        public string col7 { get; set; }

    }
  // test test1 = new test();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;           // For Background Worker
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }


    private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dg1.Items.Clear();
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       // int max = (int)e.Argument;

        for (int i = 1; ; i++)
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);


            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = e.ProgressPercentage;


        if (i > 100000)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 100)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
                { dg1.Items.RemoveAt(0); }
                count = 0;
            }
        }

            dg1.Items.Add(new test() {sno=i,col1="test",col2="test",col3="test",col4="test",col5="test",col6="test",col7="test" });



    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Task Cancelled.....");
        }

            // Check to see if an error occurred in the background process.

        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error while performing background operation." + e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            // Everything completed normally.
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Task Completed..." + e.Result);
        }
    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.CancelAsync();

    }

    private void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      //  worker.CancelAsync();
        dg1.Items.Clear();
       // GC.Collect();
    }
}
}
```

Here every time I am creating a new class test, so that it is occupying memory and is not being freed by GC. how can I avoid this?

Comment: Do you just add and clear items in your DataGrid and these operations are caused memory leaks?

Comment: Can you add the output of your memory profiler that shows the GC root path of one of the leaked items?  Also, what is your test procedure?  When you are grabbing the snapshots?

Comment: Are you getting OutOfmemoryException, or you are just watching on  memory used by your application? GC.Collec()t does not clear all unused references. You may need to call GC.Collect(2), since the Items may be considered as long lived objects: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I see that you register these events :

```
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

You need to unregister them at some point. To do this, you could implement the IDisposable interface in your class and unregister the events in the Dispose function. Something like this :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IDisposable
{
```

...

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        worker.DoWork -= worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged -= worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted -= worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }
}
```

And you could also set your BackgroundWorker to null, just in case.

Comment: The event handlers only create a strong reference of the Form in the worker, not the other way around.  The worker is held as an instance field of the form it is attached to, so there's no leak there.

Comment: i tried to declare class as Idisposable, but I didn't get. could you modify my code according to that

Comment: No need to impement Dispose here

Comment: could you give the link?   @mgarant

Answer (score 0):

**When you unsubscribe from Events**

Generally it's required to unsubscribe from events, if they are belonging to a different class or if the publisher lives longer than the subscriber. In here, backgroundWorker is your class variable and its life time scope is equals to this class instance life time. So, no need unsubscribe from those event handlers.

**When to implement IDisposable**

You should implement [IDisposable pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) if you have any class variables that have implemented IDispose interface. Simply if you have any class variables those have Dispose method, you should implement IDispose interface and Dispose all disposable objects.

**In Your code**

Apparently you have some disposable objects (objects those have Dispose methods) in your view. (at least DataGrid is disposable I think) Implement IDisposable interface and dispose all disposable objects.

Make sure you call the Dispose method appropriate after you implementing the IDisposable pattern! Just implementing it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: "Generally you should unsubscribe from events only if you are subscribing to a publisher that lives longer than your subscriber" I disagree with that statement. Firstly I believe its the wrong way round, (the publisher holds a reference to the subscriber, keeping that alive). Secondly CAN and SHOULD are very different concepts, https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt. Although the unsubscription code is unnecessary, it is not generally possible to realize that from a quick glance at the source code.

Comment: @Aron: Well, I changed to way I express it. Thanks for your comment. Regarding publisher and subscriber, that's exactly what I want to say. Publisher lives longer and keeps holding the reference to the subscriber. So, GC cannot collect the Subscriber, even though it is disposed.